# API/SDK Checkout.com - Set Phone and Shipping Address to a payment

Tags: php, checkout

I'm using Checkout.com and its [PHP SDK](https://github.com/checkout/checkout-sdk-php) to set up payment on a website.

I try to set the Phone and The Shipping Address, but i'm doing wrong i suppose.
The [API](https://api-reference.checkout.com/) is not so amazing about this as well (or i don't know how to use it to find what i want)

I did something like this for the phone but doesn't work

```
$customerPhone = new \Checkout\Models\Phone();
$customerPhone->number = $phone;
$payment->shipping = new \stdClass();
$payment->shipping->phone = $customerPhone;
```

And i have no idea for the address.

If someone knows ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of sending shipping data on payments is:

```
$shipping = new \Checkout\Models\Payments\Shipping($address, $phone);
```

Where $address is an object of Checkout\Models\Address and $phone is an object of Checkout\Models\Phone.